# Android - How to Load Image by name using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

Hi I'm using Glide to load image from my drawable folder and all works fine, this is my code :

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.my_drawable_image_name).into(myImageView);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to load the image just by name, something like :

```
Glide.with(this).load(my_drawable_image_name).into(myImageView);
```

because i want to get the image name dynamically ,for example from a database...

do you have any suggestion about that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: where image is stored?

Comment: @James, Can you share any benefit of using Glide for static drawable image ? Rather directly using setImageResource ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Call `getImage` method for get `Drawable` using Name only.

```
Glide.with(this).load(getImage(my_drawable_image_name)).into(myImageView);

public int getImage(String imageName) {

    int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

    return drawableResourceId;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Try this:**

```
Glide.with(this)
.load(getResources()
.getIdentifier("my_drawable_image_name", "drawable", this.getPackageName())
.into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Uri.

```
String image = "image.jpg";
    String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + image;

    File file = new File(completePath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this)
        .load(profileImage)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.baseline_person_24)
        .into(binding.profileIv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get `Bitmap`, `Drawable` from URL using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This code snippet is used to set `drawableEnd/drawbleRight` for `TextView`.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    bitmap: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                ) {
                    val drawable: Drawable = BitmapDrawable(
                        context.resources,
                        bitmap
                    )

                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        null, null, drawable, null
                    )
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                }
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable_image_name))
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.icon)
            .into(myImageView);
```

Load method of Glide also accept drawable object as a parameter to load image. You just have to get the drawable object from your drawable image and pass it to the load method.
I wanted rounded-corner of image and that's why I used Glide. In your case, You should use this.

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable_image_name))
```

If you also want rounded image use this.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(Glide.with(mContext)
            .transform(new FitCenter(), new RoundedCorners((int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._10sdp))
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.icon)
            .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to load image from drawable by using Name

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(context.getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable_image_name", "drawable", context.getPackageName()))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.add_photo_placeholder)
            .error(R.color.red)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
            .into(userPhoto);
```